# Gradient of LSTM one to many model output w.r.t input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, gradient-descent

I have an LSTM model that takes as input a vector x0 (dimension : n) and returns a sequence of vectors (size : T x n). I require the derivative of each sequence w.r.t x0 (size: n x n). Thus I require a Jacobian matrix of size (T x n x n). What is the most efficient way to do this in TensorFLow. I need this for optimization research that requires a function that takes x0 and returns the derivative information. Having searched all available options, I don't have any good way to approach this. Any help (psuedo code, documentations, posts etc) will be very beneficial.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but Tensorflow has eager execution (allows for interactive debugging) and a pretty comprehensive framework for automatic computation of gradients.  The combination of those two might assist.  This link includes some details and example code which may lend itself to your specific needs:  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager and in particular this section: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/eager#computing_gradients  along with others on the post.

I hope this helps.